# How to recognize or get the id of element configured in fragments from actvity[Horizontal paging]

Tags: android

is there any way to get the element id from the subclass of FragmentActivity, The element is configured through Fragment subclass?

There are 2 layout xml files. These two layout xmls are configured using 2 Fragment classes as Fragment1 and Fragment2.

These two Fragment classes are configured to FragmentActivity subclass through FragmentPagerAdapter subclass and viewpager tag to achieve the horizontal paging.

layout1.xml have 2 Text view elements. Where one is static and fixed text and another one is updated with countdown time.
layout2.xml have one EditText field and one submit button. when ever user enter the text in edit text and submit button is clicked, then the text value of EditText field will be captured in the FragmentActivity class.

Please help me.

Reagrds
mini.